# Какие алгоритмы и структуры данные используются при создании сервисов вопросов и ответов?

Tags: алгоритм, движок

Какие варианты движков встречаются? Есть ли книги по архитектурам таким систем?

Comment: самые разнообразные. собственно как и для других систем. вопросы-ответы ничем особенным среди других web-сервисов (или не web) не выделяются